# How to open a css popup during page load then close it when the page load completes

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, onload

I have a web page that takes 20-30 seconds to load.  Is it possible to open a popup ("Please wait...") that then closes when the page finishes loading?  I have tried the following, but it's not working.  The page loads as expected in all ways but one: the popup doesn't appear.  I'm using Firefox as my development platform.  When I reverse the conditions (make #container hidden/none and closePopup() resets to visible/block), it works perfectly (popup appears when page finishes loading).  As a second question, even if I get this working, will it be enormously browser dependent?  Thanks!

```
<html><head><style>
#container{
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    top : 0;
    position : absolute;
    visibility : visible;
    display: block;
    background-color : rgba(22,22,22,0.5);
}
#popup{
    position : relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 35%;
    width : 300px;
    padding : 10px;
    border : 1px solid black;
    background : yellow;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #252525;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript">
    function closePopup(){
        document.getElementById('container').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('container').style.display = "none";
    }
</script></head><body onload="closePopup();">
<div id="container"><div id="popup">Please Wait...</div></div>
20 seconds worth of stuff happens here.
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this is written it runs the script to close the popup before the popup is even loaded. The script to close the popup is loaded in the head tag and then executed as the very first attribute of the body tag, but you did not enter any contents into the popup until later on in the body. Use the defer attribute in your script tag. So that the script to close the popup is not run until the page has finished parsing. Like so:

```
<script language="javascript" defer>
function closePopup(){
    document.getElementById('container').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('container').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

To answer your second question, using the defer attribute works on practically every modern browser. Including Safari, Chrome, Firefox 3.6+, Opera 15.0+, and Edge 10.0+

Comment: According to W3, the defer attribute belongs in the <script> tag: <script language="javascript" defer>.  Further, it is only meant to be used with the src attribute to prevent JS files from executing at the time they're loaded.  I tried using this in my code as written, but it didn't help.  Note that the popup is fully realized before the 20-seconds worth of loading begins.  I suppose I could load it via Javascript, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Good point, and thank you for pointing out my mistake that is a big error in my answer.